# PHP QR Code libary image

Tags: php, qr-code

I'm trying to get an image in my QR code im using PHP QR Code libary.

i can display the QR code i just can't figure out how to put a small image on the QRcode

```
$qrcode =  QRcode::png('website url');
```

Does anybody has an idea how to get an image in the middle of the QRcode?

thanks

Comment: Once you have the image saved to your server or in php variable, use PHP GD library to place your center image over the top.

Comment: Thanks i will check it out!